# Bootstrap 4 grid col-6 resize to col-sm-3 add space between rows

Tags: grid, bootstrap-4

I'm using BS4 Beta and have a grid 4 columns wide in full screen with resize down to 2 columns smaller screen. I have `<div class="row mb-3">` to put a space between the images. When the screen gets resized smaller the images are on top of each other without space. How can I code this differently to get the space? 
I have a working codepen here https://codepen.io/mlegg10/pen/yzjRya

here is all the code

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row mb-3">
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="original_photos/1.jpg">
                       <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-fluid" alt="" src="http://ryehome.com/original_photos/1.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a></div>
   <div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="original_photos/1.jpg">
                       <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-fluid" alt="" src="http://ryehome.com/original_photos/1.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a></div>
   <!-- Add the extra clearfix for only the required viewport -->
  <div class="clearfix d-none d-sm-block"></div>
   <div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="original_photos/1.jpg">
                       <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-fluid" alt="" src="http://ryehome.com/original_photos/1.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a></div>
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="original_photos/1.jpg">
                       <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-fluid" alt="" src="http://ryehome.com/original_photos/1.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a></div>
</div>
<div class="row mb-3">
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="original_photos/1.jpg">
                       <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-fluid" alt="" src="http://ryehome.com/original_photos/1.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a></div>
   <div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="original_photos/1.jpg">
                       <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-fluid" alt="" src="http://ryehome.com/original_photos/1.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a></div>
   <!-- Add the extra clearfix for only the required viewport -->
  <div class="clearfix d-none d-sm-block"></div>
   <div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="original_photos/1.jpg">
                       <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-fluid" alt="" src="http://ryehome.com/original_photos/1.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a></div>
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="original_photos/1.jpg">
                       <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-fluid" alt="" src="http://ryehome.com/original_photos/1.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
.img-fixed{
  padding-bottom:5px;  
}
```

to your CSS file. Works just fine in your codepen.

Comment: can I adopt this method to what is a 5 column grid? I only have 10 photos to use. It's set to use 5 photos per row, I tried to make it show 2 wide in both widescreen and mobile, but the grid is based on 12. Should I make a new thread for this? It's currently live here if you want to see what I mean. http://ryesunrise.com/photos.html

Comment: @mlegg there are a lot of issues in the layout of that page, But replacing the 'col' class with 'col-lg-2 col-sm-6' in your rows will get you most of the way there.

Comment: Also, the code on your live site and the code you showed us in not even not the same. I would also try updating your code base from what you showed up to the live site. Or provide a link to recent code.

Comment: I decided just to make it 2 columns wide and used <div class="row mb-3">,<div class="col